# Geoserver LegendGraphic support for Rules in SLDs

Tags: geoserver

I want to serv custom legend via GetLegendGraphic WMS request.
I find two answers:

1. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-3747?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel
2. https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/397

On first site there is patch file to geoserver, but I don't know how to use it (where to paste it).
On second site is github so I clone repo and build geoserver by myself, but what now? I try add `<LegendGraphic> -> <Graphic> -> <ExternalGraphic> -> <OnlineResource>` to SLD file but geoserver don't validate it.

So can anyone explane how to get custom legend?